# Indoor map with route directions in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, system, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to create an indoor map navigation in android studio for my thesis project in school and I'd like to know some basics or where should I start.

I'm also planning to use images as a map with 8 floors in it unless if there's anything simpler way to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Navigine SDK](https://github.com/Navigine/Android-SDK) for this task, it allows indoor navigation through WiFi, BLE, WiFi-RTT, Eddystone.

You just create the map on [web client](https://client.navigine.com/auth/login) using your floor images, set there transmitters, download mobile app and will see the navigation.